# How to achieve the click action of UAC window in UI automation

Tags: selenium

When automating with Selenium, a UAC (user account control) window pops up as shown in Figure, need accept the relevant license. I could not use the AutoIt tool to click that.

I am searching for a long time on Internet. But no use. Please help or try to give some ideas how to achieve this.

[image]

Comment: You can't. If you could, this would be a trivial privilege escalation vulnerability.

Answer (score 0):

You can [disable UAC on the machine you're running](https://superuser.com/questions/83677/disabling-uac-on-windows-7).

If you can't, try running as administrator.

BTW, this has nothing to do with Selenium. Maybe you meant the [UI Automation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Microsoft_UI_Automation) framework by Microsoft.

Answer (score 0):

There is a simple reason why you can't find any information on this topic - it is simply not possible.  UAC is a security feature.  The UI prompt runs on a secure desktop session.  It cannot be automated.  Allowing it would be a major security hole.